# How to run semi-competing risk model without error

Tags: formula, missing-data, survival-analysis, recurrence

I work on cancer data, semi-competing risks model, this is my data and packages:
[1] "id"                  "time_recurrence"     "delta_recurrence"    "time_survival"       "delta_survival"
[6] "age_cat"             "agecat_Lower45"      "agecat_45_65"        "agecat_65Higher"     "age_cat2"
[11] "age_cat2_Lower50"    "age_cat2_51_70"      "age_cat2_70Higher"   "gender"              "BMI"
[16] "BMI_Normal"          "BMI_Overweight"      "BMI_Obese"           "metastas2othersite"  "cancer_site"
[21] "surgery"             "CRT"                 "chemo"               "n_chemo_cat"         "n_chemo_cat_no"
[26] "n_chemo_cat_Lower6"  "n_chemo_cat_6Higher" "morphology"          "grade"               "grade_WD"
[31] "grade_MD"            "grade_PD"            "tomur_size_7"        "tumor_size_4_7"      "Disease_stage"
[36] "Disease_stage_B"     "Disease_stage_C"     "Disease_stage_D"     "PT_Stage2"           "PT_Stage_T2"
[41] "PT_Stage_T3"         "PT_Stage_T4"         "PT_Stage_TX"         "PN_Stage2"           "PN_Stage21_N0"
[46] "PN_Stage21_N1"       "PN_Stage21_N2"       "PN_Stage21_Nx"       "stage1"              "DISEASE_1"
[51] "stage_site"          "intraction"

library(Formula)
library(SemiCompRisks)

> form <- Formula(time_recurrence + delta_recurrence | time_survival + delta_survival ~  intraction | intraction | intraction )
> scr01 <- FreqID_HReg(form, scrdata, model="semi-Markov", frailty=TRUE )
> Error in na.fail.default(list(time_recurrence = c(NA, 6.97809722521342,  :
> missing values in object

How to run the model without errors